# Footer covering content HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to figure out why my `<div>` element does not expand to cover everything it contains. I've seen this in Google Chrome's "Elements" view when I press Shift+Ctrl+J. I expected my "content" div to be sized to include `<p>A</p>` and `<p>B</p>`, but it doesn't.

PS-- I've read some comments that a footer is normally positioned absolute, but this is just to show the error.

**Here is the simplified page:**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #footer{
      background-color: lightblue;
      margin-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="content" align="center">
      <div style="width:50%;">
        <p align="left">
          Two divs:
          <div style="width:80%; float:left;"><p>A</p></div>
          <div style="width:20%; float:right;"><p>B</p></div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" align="center">
      <div style="width:90%;" align="center">
        Here is my footer.
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no align attribute on a div.

Comment: @DanMan Is it a newly supported option or is this an example of w3fools? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp

Comment: Run your HTML through a validator and it will most likely complain. It's also mentioned on the website you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

After

```
<div style="width:80%; float:left;"><p>A</p></div>
<div style="width:20%; float:right;"><p>B</p></div>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the quick help-- it's so unfortunate that this is necessary. Python's "minimum surprise" maxim would not apply here...

Answer (score 0):

add this to the css:

```
#content { overflow: hidden; }
```